# ASP.NET Core Structure of applications on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

I am currently learning how my applications are structured when I deploy my application to IIS. Right now, I have 3 solutions(A,B,C) that reference one central solution(Z) to get some config settings.

A, B and C are standard web applications that have references to one another.

Each application has this structure

- A.UI
- A.Data
- A.ClassLibrary

Z is a solution that contains several classes only and no Program.cs or Startup.cs. It is referenced by A, B and C. I am not able to right click and publish this as it is just a bunch of classes.

When I publish A, B and C, I can see that in the output folder, there are many dlls containing the names of the referenced project. E.g B references A.Data

Does this mean I won't need to publish A, C and Z because the dll is already included in B?

If that's the case, what happens when I make an update to Z or A and C? Do I have to republish everything else?

### Edit

My structure

App1

[image]

App2

[image]

App1.Data references App2.Data and so in App1's bin, you can find App2.Data.dll

Comment: Sorry why is this getting downvoted? I can’t really find any info on this

Comment: First, really the downvotes are just stupid. Now to your question: Z is a solution and inside you have 3 web projects (MVC, API?). Each application, (A, B and C) needs to be either under a `WebSite` or an `Application` under the same website. I think this might help you understand how this structure works on IIS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis

Comment: When you publish each app the output folder will have everything that app needs to run (e.g references to B or C). That output folder is what you publish under IIS (website or application). Now, if you change something in any of its dependencies, say App A references B, and B changed. You'll have to publish A again, and re-deploy so A contains the latest updates from B.

Comment: Also, can you post a screenshot of how your `Solution Explorer` looks like? Because it looks like you are using the term `solution` when you actually mean `Project`. In VS you have one `solution` a solution can have many `projects`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. A,B,C and Z are solutions. The difference is that A,B,C contain projects named A.UI, A.Data etc. Z solution contains a class library project that has classes such as DateConverter that is a class that only converts dates and doesn’t have a Program.cs.

Comment: Ok, want to chat a bit? This is getting to big for comments.

Comment: I’ll post a few screenshots when I get back. Thank you so much for explaining. That means there’s quite the incentive to bundle everything into one project rather than split it into its own projects and reference each other.

Comment: I'll have to see your structure before saying anything.. but it seems that it's a bit complicated and maybe you can make it simpler. Of course, bundling things together will always be simpler than having n projects, but each case is different from the other. I opened a private chat with you, so just ping me there.

Comment: I've edited my question with screenshots. I'm getting a clearer picture from what you have said so far.

Comment: Yeah so both projects are separated but share a common `Data` library. So, again, each project will be a separate `Website` or `Application` on IIS. Plus, you should really think on extracting `App2.Data` into a separate project, and distribute it as a NuGet package to both App1 and App2. It's very easy to do and will make your life so much easier in the long run, since each app can have different versions of `Data` and not necessarily need the latest version.